# If then statement using trailing 12 months over multiple spreadsheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I am trying to create a formula for:
 `If(the trailing 12 month sum is equal to $250,000, then add a sales rep,0)`

where the *trailing 12 month data* is contained in multiple worksheets and broken down by week but is contained in a single row.

I am not trying to chart the sales data, I want the cost of a sales rep to be added to my worksheet when the trailing 12 months sales equal a certain amount.

[image: Screen Shot of Data]

I'm not sure the data is set up correctly for this kind of calculation.

Comment: Your question is not sufficiently clear. Can you post a link to a screenshot?

Comment: Can you clarify "*trailing 12 month data* is contained in multiple worksheets and broken down by week but is contained in a single row"? Is there a single row where the totals are kept on each worksheet? Is it the same row every time?

Answer (score 0):

This would be much easier if you had your data organized in a table-like format.

Something like this:

```
Company | Date       | Sales
----------------------------
Acme    | 2012-30-11 | 1,000
Acme    | 2012-20-11 | 1,250
Acme    | 2012-10-11 | 1,150
Acme    | 2012-30-11 | 1,500
Acme    | 2012-20-11 | 1,200
Acme    | 2012-10-11 | 1,700
Acme    | 2012-30-11 | 1,300
Acme    | 2012-20-11 | 1,000
Acme    | 2012-10-11 | 1,050
Acme    | 2012-30-11 | 1,100
Foo     | 2012-30-11 |   500
Foo     | 2012-20-11 |   700
Foo     | 2012-10-11 |   600
Foo     | 2012-30-10 | 1,000
Foo     | 2012-20-10 |   500
Foo     | 2012-10-10 |   300
Bar     | 2012-30-11 | 1,000
Bar     | 2012-20-11 |   500
Bar     | 2012-10-11 |   800
Bar     | 2012-30-10 |   900
Bar     | 2012-20-10 |   800
Bar     | 2012-10-10 |   700
Bar     | 2012-30-09 |   500
Bar     | 2012-20-09 |   400
Bar     | 2012-10-09 |   600
Bar     | 2012-30-08 |   800
```

...would let you use [one of Excel's database functions](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Database-Functions.html) or [fancy `SUMPRODUCT` logic](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/11/10/excel-sumproduct-formula/).

Comment: This is more of a helpful hint (appropriate as a comment), than an actionable solution to the question.  Unfortunately, you're trying to answer a very unclear question, which is difficult.